# Andengine Update Timer Label

Tags: android, andengine, runnable

I try to create simple mesured time label. I try RunnableHandler, Handler and activity.this.runOnUiThread(). Every single time I got similar error.

**Error**

```
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=90; index=90
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670):     at org.andengine.entity.text.vbo.HighPerformanceTextVertexBufferObject.onUpdateVertices(HighPerformanceTextVertexBufferObject.java:124)
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670):     at org.andengine.entity.text.Text.onUpdateVertices(Text.java:333)
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670):     at org.andengine.entity.shape.Shape.setSize(Shape.java:146)
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670):     at org.andengine.entity.text.Text.setText(Text.java:221)
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670):     at pl.newaxis.szyfraki.MainActivity.updateTimerText(MainActivity.java:224)
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670):     at pl.newaxis.szyfraki.MainActivity$5$1.run(MainActivity.java:181)
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-07 03:34:40.057: E/AndroidRuntime(5670):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My current code

```
@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene, OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws IOException {
    final Thread backgroundLoading = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loadResources();
            loadScenes();
            Handler refreshScene = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            refreshScene.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loadingIndicator.detachSelf();
                    splash.detachSelf();
                    mEngine.setScene(mainScene);
                }
            });

        }
    });
    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(1f, new ITimerCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            backgroundLoading.start();
        }
    }));

    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(1f, new ITimerCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            initLoadingAnimation();
        }
    }));

    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();

}


private void loadScenes() {
    mainScene = ((MenuController) mFrame.getModule("Menu")).createMainMenu();
    final Handler updateLabel = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    Font font = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD), 32);
    font.load();
    //
    Float timerText = 0.0f;
    timerLabel = new Text(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2, font, Float.toString(timerText), this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    TimerHandler mTime = new TimerHandler(0.1f, true, new ITimerCallback() {

        float time = 0.0f;

        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            time += 0.1f;
            updateLabel.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateTimerText(time);

                }
            });

        }

    });

    mainScene.attachChild(timerLabel);
    mainScene.registerUpdateHandler(mTime);
}

void updateTimerText(float value) {
    timerLabel.setText(Float.toString(value));
}
```

Could you suggest me what I'm doing wrong? I'm using latest AndEngine with GLES 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use these many handlers which will update every time(in your case it is loading all your resources multiple times).Try to use one handler itself.And also unregister this handle after completion of loading your resources.

Comment: Ok I took care about unregister and it crash when I call ``timerLabel.setText(Float.toString(value));``

Comment: assign minimum characters into your Text lable

Comment: Thanks :) minimum characters helps :)